# Persist div fb-root after router navigation in backbone

Tags: facebook, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to integrate `Facebook JS` sdk with my `BackboneJS` spa.

When the page is new, ie; `router` has not navigated to any where, the **Facebook** share code works perfectly.

After I navigate to some other page. The `FB.api()` callbacks never fire.

The `fb-root` div `<div id="fb-root"></div>` is automatically getting created automatically.
But once i navigate to any other route, my body is getting cleared and new  html will be loaded.

How to keep the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in body while navigating to the other routes.

Or is there anyother way to getting though this issue.

pease help =)

Comment: Please post some code. When switching in and out views, you can specify where the views are inserted. You should not be emptying your body and appending your view. Instead consider emptying an element within your body tag and append your view in that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to render your views in a new element, not directly in the body :

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="container"></div> <!-- Here for example -->
</body>
```